# Load data from host to docker container and write back to host on exit. Load and Persist data between host and container

Tags: docker, containers, volume, mount, persist

My requirement is to create docker image using data in host directory. And when I run the container, the data produced in the container has to be copied back to the host directory. In simple words, data persistence.

Here is how i build and run the container (that works):

Docker build & create, starts the container with data in host location (all fine)

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker build -t myimage:latest . && > /dev/null
sudo docker create -p 8080:8080 -v host/data/location:/etc/container/data/location --name mycontainer myimage:latest && > /dev/null
```

Start container and copy data back to host for persistence.

```
#!/bin/bash
#start container
sudo docker start mycontainer && > /dev/null

#copy data on exit 
sudo docker cp mycontainer:/etc/container/data/location/. `pwd`/host/data/location/ && > /dev/null
```

I know that the best way is to mount volumes but it has been unsuccessful on copying data back to host from container. And i want to get rid of copy step.

It should work,

```
docker create -p 8080:8080 -v /host/data/location:/etc/container/data/location --name mycontainer myimage:latest
```

but it isn't! Can someone tell the reason?

Comment: Just mounting the volume to a writable directory on the host should persist any data written inside the container at that mountpoint.

Comment: The bind mount works with `docker run` command but not with `docker create`, is it supposed to?

Comment: You don't bind mount during create. you need to add/copy in the dockerile from the build context into the container.

Comment: Thanks. yes. thats what i am doing. ADD/COPY stuff in the build container step. And afterwards bindmount in run step.